# pass parameter to bean with method expression

Tags: jsf-2, methods, parameter-passing, javabeans

I have this:

```
<p:inputText id="email" styleClass="form-control"
            value="#{userRegisterBean.email}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter a email adress" />

        <p:watermark for="email" value="email adress" />


<p:inputText id="nickname" styleClass="form-control"
            value="#{userRegisterBean.nickName}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter a nickname" />
```

and calling the method with:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
            value="register" actionListener="#{userRegisterBean.addUser()}">
</p:commandButton>
```

This works fine.

But now I want something like this:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
        value="register" actionListener="#{userRegisterBean.addUser(nickname,email)}">
```

Bean:

```
    public void addUser(String nickName, String email) {
    // add my user
}
```

I do not want a extra attribute in my bean.

How can I pass one or more parameter to my bean, without an extra attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do that with

`<p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
        value="register" actionListener="#{userRegisterBean.addUser(userRegisterBean.nickname,userRegisterBean.email)}">`

... but I can't see the point. You already have nickname and email properties inside the same bean class. You don't have to pass them as arguments to the method.

Comment: That's my point. I want pass the values as arguments to my method. Is that possible with <p:inputText> ?